# Getting Cursor Position on TextInput React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the caret position of a `TextInput`? I tried `onSelectionChange` and creating an event emitter from `DocumentSelectionState` but neither appear to be working (they don't fire anything, no matter what I select).

For Example: https://rnplay.org/apps/eZnvIA

Comment: I want to know the answer too

Answer (score 30):

```
onSelectionChange={(event) => console.log(event.nativeEvent.selection)}
```

Comment: This event isn't firing correctly for me. If the caret is moved the event isn't triggered correctly.

Comment: @YungGun did you add `multiline={true}` to your textInput? It won't fire without it.

Comment: @RyanPergent That may have been a problem, I ended up using a solution that does not require the onSelectionChange event though so I'm not sure.

Comment: @RyanPergent Works without `multiline={true}` as well.

Comment: @ICW you should share the solution.

Answer (score 5):

In react-native <=v0.56 following code get the selection as an object of {state: number, end: number}. The text positions start from 0. For example selection like {start: 0, end: 0} can happen and it means your curser is placed before first character of you text and nothing selected. Another selection type happens when start and end is not equal, like {start: 0, end: 10}, this means you select first 10 character of your text.

By the way as following [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21515) if you use react native v0.57.0 or v0.57.1 in the textInput must be add multiline={true} to everything work properly.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput} from 'react-native';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        selection: {start: 0, end: 0},
        text: 'This is a sample text',
    }
}
render() {
 return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{this.state.selection.start}, {this.state.selection.end}</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{ width: 300, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
        onSelectionChange={({ nativeEvent: { selection } }) => {
          this.setState({ selection })
        }}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
    </View>
    );
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: In the last version, 0.60 this issue is resolved. The single line TextInput's `onSelectionChange` returns correct `selection` array.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to get semi-adventurous, you can update the `react-native` library to allow retrieving the cursor (x/y) coordinates (relative to the `TextInput`), in the `onSelectionChange` event parameter.

[Full instructions for IOS AND Android](https://medium.com/@p9alisand/how-to-get-textinput-cursor-position-in-react-native-0-49-1845aee40e9b). (**Disclaimer:** I did not come up with this solution - @Palisand did)

### TLDR - IOS + ReactNative 0.49.1

#### `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text/RCTTextSelection.h`

```c
/**
 * Object containing information about a TextInput's selection.
 */
@interface RCTTextSelection : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSInteger start;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSInteger end;
/* >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> */
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) CGPoint cursorPosition;

- (instancetype)initWithStart:(NSInteger)start end:(NSInteger)end cursorPosition:(CGPoint)cursorPosition;
/* <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */

@end
```

---

#### `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text/RCTTextSelection.m`

```c
@implementation RCTTextSelection
  
    /* >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> */
- (instancetype)initWithStart:(NSInteger)start end:(NSInteger)end cursorPosition:(CGPoint)cursorPosition
    /* <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */
{
  if (self = [super init]) {
    _start = start;
    _end = end;
    /* >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> */
    _cursorPosition = cursorPosition;
    /* <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */
  }
  return self;
}

@end

@implementation RCTConvert (RCTTextSelection)

+ (RCTTextSelection *)RCTTextSelection:(id)json
{
  if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSInteger start = [self NSInteger:json[@"start"]];
    NSInteger end = [self NSInteger:json[@"end"]];
    /* >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> */
    CGPoint cursorPosition = CGPointMake(
      [self CGFloat:json[@"cursorPositionX"]],
      [self CGFloat:json[@"cursorPositionY"]]
    );
    return [[RCTTextSelection alloc] initWithStart:start
                                               end:end 
                                    cursorPosition:cursorPosition];
    /* <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */
  }

  return nil;
}

@end
```

---

#### `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text/RCTTextInput.m`

```c
- (RCTTextSelection *)selection
{
  id<RCTBackedTextInputViewProtocol> backedTextInput = self.backedTextInputView;

  UITextRange *selectedTextRange = backedTextInput.selectedTextRange;
  return [[RCTTextSelection new] initWithStart:[backedTextInput offsetFromPosition:backedTextInput.beginningOfDocument toPosition:selectedTextRange.start]
                                           end:[backedTextInput offsetFromPosition:backedTextInput.beginningOfDocument toPosition:selectedTextRange.end]
      /* >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> */
                                cursorPosition:[backedTextInput caretRectForPosition:selectedTextRange.start].origin];
      /* <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */
}

...
  
- (void)textInputDidChangeSelection
{
  if (!_onSelectionChange) {
    return;
  }

  RCTTextSelection *selection = self.selection;
  _onSelectionChange(@{
    @"selection": @{
      @"start": @(selection.start),
      @"end": @(selection.end),
      /* >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> */
      @"cursorPositionX": @(selection.cursorPosition.x),
      @"cursorPositionY": @(selection.cursorPosition.y)
      /* <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: I needed the x/y position as well, and not the character position, which is what you get by default. Were you able to get this to work on Android?

Comment: @Noitidart - from memory, yes. Did you see the android instructions -> https://medium.com/@p9alisand/how-to-get-textinput-cursor-position-in-react-native-0-49-1845aee40e9b

Comment: Thanks @Nick - yes I tried the Android instructions, without forking/building-from-source. I always edited in `./node_modules/react-native/` in past and after re-compiling with `react-native run-android` and my changes took effect. However it's not taking affect here. I posted in the comments section there but no reply yet. Do you remember doing having any issues? Or any peculiar thing you did to get it to work? Did you build from source?

Comment: @Noitidart For android react-native is pre-built, thats why changes are not reflected.
For changes to take effect you need to build it from source. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-from-source.html

Comment: I came up with this extremely out-of-date solution. At least give me some credit.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the position of the cursor the only thing you need is **onSelectionChange** https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onselectionchange.
The function will return the **start** and the **end** values.

Answer (score -5):

As a start, you probably want to use the onChange or even onChangeText event instead.  That will get your alert firing.